# How add SQL request in Laravel index method?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have `foo table`, `foo model` and `foo controller`. In `test controller` i have function `index`:

```
public function index()
{
    return Foo::query(true)->filter(Request::input())->paginate()->appends(Request::input());
}
```

which return list of all elements in `foo table`.

1) How in this controller also return field `bar_id` from table `bar`, where column `type_id = 1`?

2) In table `bar` I have foreign key `bar_elements`. How with element `bar` return all `bar_elements`?

Db structure

[image]

Comment: You can do it like this `return Foo::query(true)->with('bars')->with('bar_elements')->filter(Request::input())->paginate()->appends(Request::input());
}` assuming that you have `bars` and `bar_elements` as relationships in the Foo model and Bar model successively.

Comment: @Maraboc I try like this: `return Foo::query(true)->with('bars', Bar::whereTypeId('1'))->with('bar_elements')->filter(\Request::input())->paginate()->appends(\Request::input());`, but get this - `ErrorException
mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: no you should do it like this `with(['bars' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('type_id', 1');
}])....` :)

Comment: @Maraboc `->with(['bar' => function($query){$query->where('id','1');}])->with('bar_elements')` 1) where not found 2) `Call to undefined relationship [bar_elements] on model [App\Models\Foo` (maybe this must be relation with bar, but no foo)].

Comment: Yes that's what i said in the comment !! and one more thing it's like this `->with('bars.bar_elements')`

Comment: @Maraboc Ok, thank's, request work fine, but it return Bar as element Foo, but I want that Bar was as element of all class Foo, but not of one element.

Comment: I didn't get waht you mean ?

Comment: @Maraboc I get like this:`"current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "bar": {
                "bar_elements": {
                    "id": 5,
                }
            }
        },`

Comment: But want like this: `"current_page": 1,
    "data": [
  "bar": {
                "bar_elements": {
                    "id": 5,
                }
            }
        {
            "id": 1,
        },`

Comment: in this case inverse the query you must do it like this `Bar::with('foos')->with('bar_elements) ....'`

Comment: @Maraboc Oh, sorry, You don't understand me. I want do display `Bar` as additional information in `Foo`, but not as element of `Foo` with id 1.

Comment: ok wait this query `->with(['bar' => function($query){$query->where('id','1');}])` will return for evry Foo a bar with id = 1 if there is one, so if you want your bar all you must do is `$foo->bars`this will return a collection of bars that you loaded in this case just one bar with id = 1 !!

Comment: @Maraboc thank's for your answer and sorry for my obtusity)

Comment: It's ok i will post an answer that you can accept to help poeple find it because most of them don't read comments !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function index()
{
    return Foo::query(true)->with(['bars' => function ($query) { 
                                        $query->where('id', 1'); 
                                    }])
                           ->with('bars.bar_elements')
                           ->filter‌​(Request::input())
                           ->‌​paginate()
                           ->appends(‌​Request::input()); 
    } 
}
```

Assuming that you have `bars` in Foo model and `bar_elements` in Bar model as relationships.

This query `->with(['bar' => function($query){$query->where('id','1');}])`
 will return for evry Foo a bar with id = 1 if there is one, so if you want your bar all you must do is `$foo->bars` this will return a collection of bars that you loaded in this case just one bar with id = 1 or `null` if there is no bar.

Comment: @nafumat you can accept the answer --> [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)